# Camunda could not read xml from http-connector response in inline script

Tags: xml, inline, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to parsing xml body from http response.

Here is what I want and what I'm doing.

1. I made simple bpmn file which is request api and get the response from api server.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIdLe.png)

2. I want to parsing the response and response consist of xml.
   I can see the all xml data when I put the $(XML(response)} in output value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><deployment xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <deployment_details>
    <host_uuid>1963aa56409abe71d8c449d6e2adf3eb816e8ccf75838bfa664ef803</host_uuid>
    <host_name>my_hostname</host_name>
    <vm_uuid>02c644ed-1a92-4efb-b80b-f1abbf5ea3b6</vm_uuid>
    <generated_vm_name>esc-vnf-info-csr_csr-te_0_bf4121de-cd55-4b14-ad7a-6d4a3f572e02</generated_vm_name>
    <interfaces>
      <interface>
        <binding_profile/>
        <network_uuid>b76e4cd7-0d88-4889-b6fe-2430641c26cc</network_uuid>
        <gateway>172.18.21.254</gateway>
        <ip_address>172.18.21.132</ip_address>
        <mac_address>fa:16:3e:17:86:67</mac_address>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <nic_id>0</nic_id>
        <port_forwarding/>
        <port_uuid>6c38a416-48b6-45d2-b192-2fe9971c1ed2</port_uuid>
        <port_security_enabled>false</port_security_enabled>
        <security_groups/>
        <subnet_uuid>41330856-a0c9-4a04-be5b-b513c761da0e</subnet_uuid>
        <type>virtual</type>
        <vim_interface_name>esc-vnf-info-csr_csr-te_0_bf4121de-cd55-4b14-ad7a-6d4a3f572e02</vim_interface_name>
      </interface>
    </interfaces>
  </deployment_details>
  <deployment_name>info-csr-test</deployment_name>
</deployment>
```

3. final goal is to get the hostname
   /deployment/deployment_details/host_name
   As for this I put the value as below

```
${XML(response).xPath("/deployment/deployment_details/host_name").element()}
```

Cannot instantiate process definition esc_api_test:12:782eb51a-d4ec-11ec-ab99-5af27468b181: Error while evaluating expression: ${XML(response).xPath("/deployment/deployment_details/host_name").element()}. Cause: org.camunda.spin.xml.SpinXPathException: SPIN/DOM-XML-01035 Unable to find XPath expression '/deployment/deployment_details/host_name' [ start-instance-error ]

Does someone help my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found other way to get the value as below code.
xPath is not working but childElement is working well.
${XML(response).childElement("deployment_details").childElement("host_name").textContent()}